# Apply input event to each dynamically added text inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

In `createInput()`, will return the dynamically created text inputs, each character from the string were assigned into `data-str` attr.

the outcome I need is to disable the input and assign a class "green" if `data-str` and `input value` matches then focus the next input, add a class "red" if it returns false...

The code below will only detect changes on first input.

Additional question: What would be the condition to apply when all inputs found a match?

```js
str = 'hello'

function createInput(s) {
  var splitStr = s.split("");
  var inputs = "";
  
  for (var i in splitStr) {
    inputs = inputs + '<input id="gwInput" type="text" data-str="' + splitStr[i] + '" autocomplete="off" maxlength="1"></input>';
  }
  
  return inputs
}
$(document).on("input", "#gwInput", function() {
  $this = $("#gwInput")
  inputValue = $this.val();
  stringValue = $this.data("str");
  
  if (stringValue === inputValue) {
    $this.prop("disabled", true).addClass("green").removeClass("red").next().focus()
  } else {
    $this.addClass("red")
  }
});

$('.container').html(createInput(str))
```

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  outline: 0
}

.green { border: 1px solid green; }
.red { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" />
```

Comment: Id's have to be **unique**

Comment: use  `createElement()` instead of building it from a string, so that you have a DOM element, and so you can attach to it a event listener (https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: Don't use `for...in...` for arrays -> [Why is using “for…in” for array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change to use class for the inputs. In your current code, you used id, so the event handler will only apply for one input only.

```js
var str = 'hello',
    strLen = str.length,
    matched = 0;

function createInput(s) {
    var splitStr = s.split("");
    var inputs = "";
    for (var i in splitStr) {
        inputs = inputs + '<input class="gwInput" type="text" data-str="' + splitStr[i] + '" autocomplete="off" maxlength="1"></input>';
    }
    return inputs
}
$(document).on("input", ".gwInput", function() {
    inputValue = $(this).val();
    stringValue = $(this).data("str");
    if (stringValue === inputValue) {
        $(this).prop("disabled", true).removeClass("red").addClass("green").next().focus();
        matched++;
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("red")
    }
   
    if (matched === strLen) {
        $('#message').show();
    }
});
$('.container').html(createInput(str))
```

```css
 input{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  outline:0
}
.green {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.red {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#message {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
<div id="message">Success</div>
```

Update additional question. Because you disabled the inputs after it matched, so we can use an easy way to achieve it. Just need to define an iterator and compare it with the string length.

Comment: Thanks Sir for the quick answer! if it's not too much to ask, pls see my updated question and provide a solution..:)

Comment: What do you mean about the "match" between inputs?

Comment: when all inputs found a match, I need to add a "success" message..

Comment: You can check my answer again

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same value in ID attribute for multiple elements. So you need to replace

`id="gwInput"` with `class="gwInput"`

and

`$this = $("#gwInput")` with `$this = $(this)`

Also, you can use spread operator and `Array.map()` to iterate over the string and map it to input elements.

```js
str = 'hello'

function createInput(s) {
  return [...s].map(letter => '<input class="gwInput" type="text" data-str="' + letter + '" autocomplete="off" maxlength="1"></input>').join("") 
}

$(document).on("input", ".gwInput", function() {
  $this = $(this)
  inputValue = $this.val();
  stringValue = $this.data("str");
  
  if (stringValue === inputValue) {
    $this.prop("disabled", true).addClass("green").next().focus()
  } else {
    $this.addClass("red")
  }
});

$('.container').html(createInput(str))
```

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  outline: 0
}

.green { border: 1px solid green; }
.red { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" />
```